# openshift wordpress plugin needs to be granted write access, how do this?

Tags: wordpress, permissions, openshift, civicrm

I am trying to install CiviCRM in my openshift wordpress 'gear' And I am getting the following when I attempt to run civicrm's installation wizard:

> The user account used by your web-server - 542ddc2950044666c40008d9 -
>   needs to be granted write access to the following directory in order
>   to configure the CiviCRM settings file:
>   //var/lib/openshift/542ddc2950044666c40008d9/app-root/data/plugins/files

Does anyone know if what it is asking is possible? 
and then how do I go about setting that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugins/files/civicrm directory is where CiviCRM stores its cached templates, file attachments, premium (thank-you gift) images, and more.  It'll need to save stuff there regularly, not just at first.

The best thing to do is to log in through SSH like developercorey recommends and:

- cd ~/app-root/plugins
- chmod 755 files (changing the permissions so the owner can write and everyone can read/execute)
- chown 542ddc2950044666c40008d9:542ddc2950044666c40008d9 files (making the user that the web server runs as ("542ddc2950044666c40008d9" as mentioned in the error message) be the owner of the directory
- have the installer check again

Answer (score 0):

1. SSH into your gear using the rhc ssh  command
2. cd ~/app-root/plugins
3. ls -lah
   Look for the "files" directory and see what the user and the permissions are on that folder, you can change with the "chmod" command to allow it to be written to by the web server, but be careful what you do or you could cause a major headache for yourself (like getting your WP blog hacked).  Hopefully the instructions for that plugin include setting the permissions to something reasonable when you are done.